# How to while loop JSON requests?

Tags: php, mysql, json, while-loop

I have to get the value from database and fetch to JSON request, but in database there can be different values. i mean in some case there can be 5 columns those columns data should be get fetch to JSON request. in some case there can be less than 5 columns. it depends.

```
<?php

$sql3 = "SELECT pic from ad_pictures WHERE adid='$adid'";
$rs3  = mysql_query($sql3,$link);

$i = 0;
while ($row3 = mysql_fetch_assoc($rs3)) {
   $pic = $row3['pic'];

?>
<script>

$("#input-fcount-3").fileinput({
    maxFileCount: 5,
    minFileCount: 2,
    validateInitialCount: true,
    overwriteInitial: false,
    showUpload:false,
    initialPreview: [
        "<img style='height:160px' src='<?php echo $pic?>'>",
    ],
    initialPreviewConfig: [
        {caption: "Ad-Picture-01", width: "120px", url: "ad_pic_delete.php", key: '<?php echo $i ?>', extra: {adid: <?php echo $adid; ?>}},
    ],
    allowedFileExtensions: ["jpg", "png"]
});
</script>
<?php

$i++;

}
```

According to SQL results data should be fetch to initialPreview `<img src="">` and initialPreviewConfig `key` should increase.

Comment: what's your expected output?